# error handling and image type cat get it to work

Tags: php

I been working on this image script for too long now, and I still can't seem to get two things to work - the image type and error handling (if the fields are empty). I have the code for this, but every place I try to add it, it doesn't work.

my code:

```
$error_message="";
$MaxSize = "600000";
if (isset($_POST['btn_update'])){
function createRandomPassword() {
$chars = "abcde!@#%^fghijkmnoABCDEFGHIJKpqrstuvwxyz023456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZ!@#%^&";
srand((double)microtime()*10000000);
$i = 0;
$pass = '' ;
while ($i <= 19) {
$num = rand() % 60;
$tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);
$pass = $pass . $tmp;
$i++;
}
return $pass;
}
if ($_FILES['aMyUploads0']['size'] > $MaxSize || $_FILES['aMyUploads1']['size'] > $MaxSize || $_FILES['aMyUploads2']['size'] > $MaxSize)
{
$error_message = "ERROR: File too big!";

}
$aMyUploads = array();
$password = createRandomPassword();
foreach($_FILES as $aFile)
{
$newLocation = 'uploads/'.$password .$aFile["name"];
if(0 === $aFile['error'] && (false !== move_uploaded_file($aFile['tmp_name'], $newLocation)))
{
$aMyUploads[] = $newLocation;
}
else
{
$aMyUploads[] = '';
}
}
$error_message="Journal successfully saved.";
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "????", "???");
mysql_select_db("????", $connection);
$insert = "INSERT INTO photos (image1, image2, image3) VALUES
(
' ".$aMyUploads[0]." ',
' ".$aMyUploads[1]." ',
' ".$aMyUploads[2]." '
)";
$add_member = mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
}

code im trying to add with no luck:



 //ERROR HANDLING CODE:

    if(empty($aMyUploads[0]) || empty($aMyUploads[1]) || empty($aMyUploads[2]))
    {
    $error_message="Please fill in all fields.";
    }
    else
    {
    $error_message="Journal successfully saved.";


//IMAGE TYPE CODE:

$allowed_filetypes = array(".jpg", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".png");

$ext = substr($newLocation, strpos($newLocation,'.'), strlen($newLocation)-1);
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
{
die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');
}
```

Comment: Is your code normally all left aligned? Indenting your code (at least in the question so it's easier to read) would be beneficial

Answer (score 0):

Try this for checking required fields, inserted before the code that checks the file sizes.

```
// ERROR HANDLING CODE:
if (empty($_FILES) || empty($_FILES['aMyUploads0']) || empty($_FILES['aMyUploads1']) || empty($_FILES['aMyUploads2']))
{
    // Handle error
}
```

And this for validating file types, inserted into your `foreach`.

```
// IMAGE TYPE CODE:

$allowed_filetypes = array("jpg", "gif", "jpeg", "png");

$ext = pathinfo($aFile['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (!in_array($ext, $allowed_filetypes))
{
    // Handle error
}
```